# Configuring XDebug within a VM using port forwarding

Tags: php, xdebug

I have a Vagrant VirtualBox VM connected to my desktop via NAT Port Forwarding (due to a VPN and database access rules, bridging the VM is not possible) and I am trying to set up XDebug within the PHP instance.

Fairly straightforward task when using a local WAMP setup, but not so much within the context of NAT. I've attempted to turn on a Port Forwarding rule in VirtualBox on port 9000, which changes nothing (NetBeans claims its waiting for a connection). I've tried using PuTTY to tunnel another port with the same results.

I'm not sure what else I should try here to make this work. I'm looking at `xdebug.remote_connect_back` as an option but it appears that my IDE isn't even attempting to make a connection. Any ideas on where to look next?

Here's my XDebug settings (Running on CentOS 7 w/ PHP 5.4.16)

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

VirtualBox has three ports forwarded: 8889 to VM 80 (for httpd), 2497 to 22 (for ssh), 9000 for 9000 (for XDebug). PuTTY has port 9690 tunneled to 9000.

Comment: 9000 is the default port for FastCGI PHP.

Comment: Good to know -- i'll use another port on the Guest VM.